# using regular expressions in if statement conditions

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

i am trying to get a php if statement to have the rule where if a set variable equals "view-##" where the # signifies any number. what would be the correct syntax for setting up an if statement with that condition?

```
if($variable == <<regular expression>>){
    $variable2 = 1;
}
else{
    $variable2 = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the `preg_match()` function:

```
if(preg_match("/^view-\d\d$/",$variable)) { .... }
```

[EDIT] OP asks additionally if he can isolate the numbers.

In this case, you need to (a) put brackets around the digits in the regex, and (b) add a third parameter to `preg_match()`.

The third parameter returns the matches found by the regex. It will return an array of matches: element zero of the array will be the whole matched string (in your case, the same as the input), the remaining elements of the array will match any sets of brackets in the expression. Therefore `$matches[1]` will be your two digits:

```
if(preg_match("/^view-(\d\d)$/",$variable,$matches)) {
     $result = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: is there anyway i could isolate the digits into a variable?

Answer (score 5):

You should use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Example:

```
if(preg_match(<<regular expression>>, $variable))
{
 $variable1 = 1;
}
else
{
  $variable2 = 2;
}
```

Also consider the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) if you are only doing an assignment:

```
$variable2 = preg_match(<<regular expression>>, $variable) ? 1 : 2;
```